# Retrieve two database column fields in one textbox VB.NET MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have this search function to search for `Firstname` `Middlename` individually with their own `CheckBox`, this thing came to my mind if i want to search for `Firstname` and `Middlename` together in one `Textbox` with space of course and tried to use `SELECT` statement with `CONCAT`, but it didn't work.

it looks like this one:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
            SQL = "SELECT * from student where CONCAT(fname,"" "", mname) like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
  SQL = "SELECT * from student where CONCAT(fname,' ', mname) like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
End if
```

### **EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE MATCH (fname, mname) AGAINST ('+" & TextBox1.Text & "* +" & TextBox1.Text & "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Might be this will give you the desired result

Comment: still doesn't work, if i press `space` after the Firstname, it shows nothing.

Comment: @SkyScraper- I think then you must have a look on [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)